# Is it appropriate to include an option to edit multiple rows at once for a CRUD page?

Tags: user-experience, crud

Let's say we have a situation in which we have a particular entity, for example an `User` which has a set of related entities e.g `Book`.

At some point in time, a group of users phisically receives a new `Book`.

That means that each user in that particular group has now a new `Book`.

At this point someone has to connect to a page used to manage the users and either

1. Edit each `User` who got a new book, one by one.
2. Select all the Users in the group and add the book to all of them in one single operation.
3. Skip the part where someone has to manually insert data and automatically update the database when something changes.
   This would probably be the best solution, but for reasons that go beyond the technical side (e.g customer requires that updates are manually inserted) not always feasible.

While browsing different pre-packaged solutions, i haven't been able to found a solution which allows what i have described in point 2.

Some of the pre-made GUIs i looked at include :

- https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/getting-started-core/
- https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPNetCore/Demo/DataGrid/

I am aware that the solution in point number 2 is prone to some problems (e.g. if two users are selected, what books are displayed to the user visiting the page? The books of the first user? The books of the second? The books which both users have? The books that at least one of the two users has?)

Still, i haven't been able to found a pre packaged solution for multi line edits, and this led me to ask myself

1. Is it because for the backend i am currently using, which is ASP.NET Core, none of the companies who create pre made GUIs have created a multi-line edit option and i should just create a multi-line edit option myself?
2. Have i been looking in the wrong direction and multi-line edit is available, even in pre-made packages and i have just missed it?
3. Should multi-line edits be avoided all together?
4. Does any of what i am asking make any sense at all? Am i completely missing something?

Comment: Also, this question seems to be premised on the idea that there is one true answer out there, and only one acceptable way of displaying that information. There really isn't. Some ideas may be better than others but much like always, this is a "build what you need/what works" situation.

Comment: _"Skip the part where someone has to manually insert data and manually update the database when something changes."_ You're suggesting manually altering the database is not a subset of manually inserting data. How did you come to that conclustion?

Comment: @Flater Thank you: i have corrected the question . What i should have written was "Skip the part where someone has to manually insert data and **automatically** update the database when something changes"

Comment: "multi-line" does not refer to affecting multiple data rows, it refers to a textbox which allows for more than one line of text (i.e. text with newlines, not just a single line even if wrapped over multiple graphical lines). As a simple example, you typed this question in a multi-line textbox, but I'm typing this comment in a single-line textbox.

Comment: Yes, it can make sense to let the user edit multiple rows at once. No, this is not the place to ask if the UI framework you are currently using supports this out of the box (Stackoverflow would be appropriate). No, this is not the place to ask how such a feature should be designed in a user-friendly manner (UX.Stackexchange might be better suited). Do do you have a real question our experts here can help you with?

Comment: @Doc Brown No i have not. I think i have mixed up a bit the various stackexchange platforms; Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing in option 2 isn't actually a multi-line edit, but a list of checkboxes, which is used often enough in UIs. But MLEs for entering multiple single-line values are also used in standard software, for example in Mailman where you can add a list of addresses to a mailing list in one step.

Just do it in a way that feels most natural and comfortable to the user. Constraining the user to single-item operations because you think that CRUD needs to work that way is the wrong approach.